# redirect not working with thymeleaf and JSP View resolver

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, redirect, view, thymeleaf

I want to use thymeleaf and jsp both in same project, but unable to jump from one controller to another.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="viewNames" value="jsp/*" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <beans:property name="cacheable" value="true" />

  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <beans:property name="viewNames" value="template/*" />
  </beans:bean>
```

Using simple code

```
return "redirect:/mycontroller";
```

Error is

```
 Could not resolve view with name 'redirect:/mycontroller' in servlet with name 'appServlet'

    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
```

Any Help how to redirect to another controller or resolve view for redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've declared `viewNames` in both your `ViewResolver` beans

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="viewNames" value="jsp/*" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <beans:property name="viewNames" value="template/*" />
</beans:bean>
```

The `viewNames` property, [for Thymeleaf for example](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring3/2.0.8/org/thymeleaf/spring3/view/ThymeleafViewResolver.html#getViewNames%28%29), states

> Return the set of name patterns that will applied to determine whether
>   a view name returned by a controller will be resolved by this resolver
>   or not. [...] Also note that these view name patterns are checked
>   **before** applying any prefixes or suffixes to the view name, so they should not include these.

Therefore,

```
"redirect:/mycontroller"
```

will not be resolved by any of the two `ViewResolver` beans. You will need to prefix that path with `template/` or `jsp/` depending on which `ViewResolver` you want to do the redirection. Both have that capability.

Comment: adding prefix means , add template/ or jsp/ before redirect:/mycontroller i.e. "template/redirect:/mycontroller" ??

Answer (score 4):

Redirects using this format did not work for me:

```
template/redirect:/mycontroller
jsp/redirect:/somepage.jsp
```

I simply defined another view resolver with

```
viewNames as redirect*
```

to handle redirects as shown below:

```
<beans:bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  <beans:property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*" />
</beans:bean>    

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="viewNames" value="jsp/*" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewNames" value="redirect*" />
</beans:bean>
```